# Unwrap > Follow Active Quads tool doesn't work

Tags: uv

I am trying to straighten my UVs which i unwrapped using sphere projection, but the follow quad tool just isnt working ... I have tried it multiple times.

[image]

[image]

Everytime i use "follow active quad" after positioning my central face and scaling its vertices in X and Y at 0, i keep getting that flat uv which does not really resemble my model.

---

**Edit:**

[image]

From your personal experience, do the uvs still look stretched to you guys?

Comment: Are you selecting all of the faces THEN the straightened face last BEFORE using it? I actually made a quick tutorial a while back on how to do this so it might help:
https://youtu.be/h0VC1njc8w4

Comment: could you please share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I made an object similar to yours and actually _Sphere Projection_ gives me straightened UVs if I set _Direction_ > _Align to Object_, and _Follow Active Quads_ also gives me straightened UVs (but the _Sphere Projection_ preserves the correct aspect of the faces). Are you trying to straighten those already distorted UVs or have you reset the UVs before unwrapping them with _Follow Active Quads_? If not, the result might be quite different.

Comment: i created 2 identities because i couldnt find a way to log into my first account, so i just created another

Comment: thanks @TheJovialBrit brit...it helped out..my UVs are..simingly straight. i appreciate the help!

Comment: i hadnt tried to reset, but i think i'll do it in my next project..you guys are super helpful!

Comment: Are you selecting all of the faces THEN the straightened face last BEFORE using it? I actually made a quick tutorial a while back on how to do this so it might help: [Example](http://youtu.be/h0VC1njc8w4)

Answer (score 3):

... it is designed like this. There is misunderstanding which *active quad* is followed ...
It doesn't follow mesh face shape, but already unwrapped UV face shape ...

Plane in Edit mode ... UV Map with Vertex edit ... Unwrap > Follow Active Quad
[image]

... Reset helps, because UV of active face become square :) Check [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html?highlight=unwrap#follow-active-quads) (Note)

---

Anyway in your case ... When I try to create something similar to your model with same Seams I Unwrapped like this ...

[image]

First - in edit mode select all faces ...

- Unwrap > Reset
- Unwrap > Cube Projection - for top and bottom part selected
- Unwrap > Unwrap - for selected sides selected

[image]

If your result is stretched, check if Scale of your object is one in all axis.
If not Apply Scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> before Unwrap.